# "Darum" and the position of the verb

Tags: grammar

Where is the verb situated when we start a sentence with the word "darum"? What place does the verb occupy?

Is it..

> Darum bin ich krank.

or

> Darum ich krank bin

Comment: What @fifaltra is saying is that from the fact that we can read your question here, we can already conclude that you wanted to ask that question. Be sure to tell us if someone forced you to ask a question without you wanting it, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Darum bin ich krank** is the proper way to construct such a sentence.  Note that "darum," in this case, is an adverb of cause and as such its construction is so.  More on this here: http://german.about.com/od/grammar/a/Adverbs-Of-Cause.htm

Comment: Actually "darum" is first and foremost a "prepositional adverb", the adverb of cause is a side effect of that. It doesn't always mean "cause". Whichever object connected via "um" can be replaced using "darum"

Comment: @Emanuel Thanks Emanuel.  I updated the answer to reflect that it acts as such in this particular case, but as a side note, would you mind going into greater detail with regard to your last sentence in your comment?  I don't quite understand it and would love to know more.  :)

Comment: @Emanuel i wanted to say:" therefore I am sick". The translation is "darum bin ich Krank". Is that correct?

Comment: @dustin... well, take "gehen um" - "to be about"... "Bei der Konferenz ging es darum, sich auf neue Klimaziele zu einigen".   Or in a simple "local" sense. "Auf dem Hügel stand ein Turm. Darum stand ein Kreis aus Bäumen."... you can find some more examples in an article I have written about "gehen um" on my blog http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/gehen-um-umgehen-german/ and for completion, here's an article on the da-words: http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/da-words-meaning-german/

Comment: @HaleemHusnu... yap, its perfectly correct.

Comment: @Emanuel Thanks :)  I understand the da- words pretty well, just didn't quite understand your phrasing of "object connected via."  That confused me a bit but I understand what you were saying now.

Answer (score 2):

The first one. If you split the sentences into contiguous parts, the conjugated verb is always at the second position of the sentence (except questions, sub-clauses and imperative).

For example:

> Darum | bin | ich | krank.
>
> Ich | esse | einen Kuchen.
>
> Die alte, geschwätzige und unzuverlässige Dame (this is one contiguous part, called the subject) | ist | auf dem Glatteis | ausgerutscht.
>
> Die Sonne | scheint | heute.

or you change the word order:

> Heute | scheint | die Sonne.

The first variation emphasizes the word "Sonne", the second one emphasizes "heute".

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange! I allowed myself to add some formatting, if you click edit you can see how it is done, so you know for the next time. I also added that the word-order is also different for sub-clauses. Should be visible in around half an hour. If you are unhappy with my edits, you can of course edit again. (If you do, make sure to capitalize German, I just saw I forgot that one.)

Answer (score 0):

it's "darum bin ich krank" - that's the correct placement. the other version you provided is how yoda talks in the german translation of the star wars movies.. it's wrong though

Comment: Wouldn't Yoda have used: " Darum krank ich bin."? Which is also wrong of course.